# NHibernate collection mapping: it's deleting and inserting instead of updating

Tags: nhibernate, insert, mapping, bag

I'm not sure how to map a collection to update.
I have 2 tables:

- Object - has a composite PK of 3 ints
- ObjectAliases - has a FK to Object and a nvarchar PK for Name, obviously name is unique

Object can have many aliases but alias name is unique for each object.

So I need to list aliases in my Object, so I did:

```
public virtual IList<string> Aliases { get; set; }
```

and my mapping is:

```
<bag name="Aliases" table="Aliases" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
  <key>
    <column name="OtpadId_Djelatnost" sql-type="nvarchar"/>
    <column name="OtpadId_Proces" sql-type="nvarchar"/>
    <column name="OtpadId_Vrsta" sql-type="nvarchar"/>
  </key>
  <element column="Ime" type="String"/>
</bag>
```

I can create and delete object from Aliases list without a problem, Nhibernate will insert and delete fine. But how can I rename an Alias? I have FKs to Alias by name and when I rename an alias I want NHibernate to do sql UPDATE so UPDATE CASCADE executes on all FKs, referencing the new name.

If I do:

```
object.Aliases[0] = "test";
```

Nhibernate will try to do a INSERT instead of UPDATE.. how can I make it do an UPDATE?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bag is unordered and unindexed collection (from http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-mapping). So I guess it comes from this fact that nhibernates deletes an recreates its content.

Comment: you're totally right... I found this quote: "NHibernate can't create, delete or update rows individually, because there is no key that may be used to identify an individual row." .. so I'll try with indexed collection and report.

Comment: I've found that you can't do this (with the table structure I have). If you try to use indexed list you need an index column, which can't be the same as element column.
Finally I resolved it by putting inverse="true" on the list and manage updating aliases myself.